# How to iterate a key over a list of lists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm a bit stumped with this right now.  I want to take a list of keys and iterate it over a list of lists

```
tests = ['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3']
scores = [[90, 70, 60], [40, 50, 100], [60, 65, 90], [30, 61, 67], 
[80, 79, 83], [70, 97, 100]]
```

Expected outcome:

I want to return a dictionary that shows the following:

```
'test 1': 90,'test 2' : 70, 'test 3': 60, 'test 1': 40, 'test 2': 50, 
'test 3': 100... 'test 1' : 70, 'test 2' : 97, 'test 3':100
```

test 1: score 1

test 2: score 2

test 3: score 3

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Comment: `dictionary that shows the following:` - that is not a valid Python dictionary (duplicate keys).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dict` with `zip`:

```
[dict(zip(tests, score)) for score in scores]
```

Output:

```
[{'test 1': 90, 'test 2': 70, 'test 3': 60},
 {'test 1': 40, 'test 2': 50, 'test 3': 100},
 {'test 1': 60, 'test 2': 65, 'test 3': 90},
 {'test 1': 30, 'test 2': 61, 'test 3': 67},
 {'test 1': 80, 'test 2': 79, 'test 3': 83},
 {'test 1': 70, 'test 2': 97, 'test 3': 100}]
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. However, I have noticed many people saying that dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys. I'm a bit confused by this because what you created is still considered a dictionary.

Comment: @Jacky actually it is a list of dictionaries with the shown result containing a list of five dictionaries.  Each of these contains the unique keys 'test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3'.

Comment: As @DarrylG pointed out, this is **not** a single dict. Single dict cannot contain duplicated keys. If you must have one dict, i recommend you taking @Ajax1234’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys, however, you can use a list of tuples:

```
tests = ['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3']
scores = [[90, 70, 60], [40, 50, 100], [60, 65, 90], [30, 61, 67], [80, 79, 83], [70, 97, 100]]
result = [(a, b) for i in scores for a, b in zip(tests, i)]
```

Output:

```
[('test 1', 90), ('test 2', 70), ('test 3', 60), ('test 1', 40), ('test 2', 50), ('test 3', 100), ('test 1', 60), ('test 2', 65), ('test 3', 90), ('test 1', 30), ('test 2', 61), ('test 3', 67), ('test 1', 80), ('test 2', 79), ('test 3', 83), ('test 1', 70), ('test 2', 97), ('test 3', 100)]
```

An even better approach is to group the integers by their target key:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in scores:
   for a, b in zip(tests, i):
      d[a].append(b)

print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'test 1': [90, 40, 60, 30, 80, 70], 'test 2': [70, 50, 65, 61, 79, 97], 'test 3': [60, 100, 90, 67, 83, 100]}
```